# Krajee Bootstrap File Input: Send files with the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, bootstrap-4

I can not send the form along with the selected files. I've tried the two methods that are in [Doc](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo#). I need to send everything together by clicking the submit button on the form.

HTML

```
<input id="inputfile" name="file[]" type="file" multiple>
```

JS

```
$("#inputfile").fileinput({
        theme: "fas",
        uploadUrl: "{% url 'publication:publish' %}",
        uploadAsync: false,
        overwriteInitial: false,
        autoReplace: false,
        autoOrientImage: true,
        minFileCount: 1,
        maxFileCount: 4,
        uploadIcon : "<i class='fas fa-upload'></i>",
        removeIcon : "<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>",
        browseIcon : "<i class='fas fa-search-plus'></i>",
        removeClass : 'btn btn-danger',
        showUpload: false,
        purifyHtml: true,
        maxFileCount: 10,
        uploadExtraData:{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        fileActionSettings: {
            showUpload: false,
        },
    });
});


$('#form-publication').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#form-publication').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "publication:publish" %}',
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        data: {
            data: form,
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', "{{csrf_token}}");},
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Can I submit everything together by clicking the submit button? I did tests sending only the images through the plugin, they are received in the server, they are stored in memory, but this POST is useless, because the form data is not sent together.Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this using this approach:

```
<form id="my-form">
    ...other fields
    <input class="archivos" name="archivos[]" type="file" multiple>
</form>
```

the configuration:

```
$('.archivos').fileinput({
    language: 'es',
    // uploadUrl: '#',
    showPreview: true,
    showUpload: false,
    browseOnZoneClick: true,
    allowedPreviewTypes: false,
    maxFileSize: 15000,
    // uploadAsync: false,
    uploadAsync: true,
    theme: "explorer-fas",
    removeFromPreviewOnError: true,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
    maxFileCount: 10,
    overwriteInitial: false,
    fileActionSettings: {
        showUpload: false,
        showZoom: false,
    },
});
```

**it's very important to note that uploadUrl is commented because the plugin will work fine with our purposes. Also to assign uploadAsync as true.**

With this, We may send the form like:

```
data = new FormData($('#my-form')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: '/Store',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, // Important
    processData: false, // Important
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('great!');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log('fail');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**!

My Ajax:

```
$('#form-publication').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).get(0)); // Creating a formData using the form.
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "publication:publish" %}',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: false, // Important!
        contentType: false, // Important! I set dataType above as Json
        data: formData, // Important! The formData should be sent this way and not as a dict.
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', "{{csrf_token}}");},
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

My Bootstrap File Input configuration:

```
$("#inputfile").fileinput({
        theme: "fas",
        uploadUrl: "{% url 'publication:publish' %}",
        uploadAsync: true, // Upload using Ajax
        overwriteInitial: false,
        autoReplace: false,
        autoOrientImage: true,
        minFileCount: 1,
        maxFileCount: 4,
        uploadIcon : "<i class='fas fa-upload'></i>",
        removeIcon : "<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>",
        browseIcon : "<i class='fas fa-search-plus'></i>",
        removeClass : 'btn btn-danger',
        showUpload: false, // Removing upload button from form
        purifyHtml: true,
        maxFileCount: 10,
        uploadExtraData:{'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}, // Send csrf token in submission
        fileActionSettings: {
            showUpload: false, // Removing upload button from action settings
        },
    });
```